# Hadoop adding datanode with smaller hard drives

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

We are planning to add two new datanodes to our Hadoop cluster. After googling for one day , i can still not answer this question:
What will happen if the hard drives are smaller on the new datanodes?
Will this result in smaller total size of the HDFS ?

Here is an example

```
Datanode1 with 1TB
Datanode2 with 1TB
Total storage = 2TB
```

Adding one more node with 500GB disk

```
Datanode3 with 500GB
```

What will be the total HDFS storage ? 2.5TB or 1.5TB ?

If it will be 2.5TB (I hope so) , how hadoop balances the storage around different datanodes with different hard drives ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The total HDFS capacity will be 2.5 TB. The existing blocks will be there as is and won't be moved to the new node once it is added to the cluster. To move some of the blocks from the overloaded to the underloaded node use the `bin/start-balancer.sh` and the `bin/stop-balancer-sh` script in the Hadoop installation.

The block placement policy will determine where the clocks will go to. Since the new nodes HDD is empty, there is a better probability that the blocks of the new files put into HDFS will go there.

Comment: OK. I think i figured it out now.
BlockPlacementPolicyDefault.java :

`/* judge if a node is a good target.`
`* return true if <i>node</i> has enough space,`
`* does not have too much load, and the rack does not have too  many nodes`
`*/`
`private boolean isGoodTarget(DatanodeDescriptor node,`
`long blockSize, int maxTargetPerLoc,`
`List<DatanodeDescriptor> results) {`
`//
`}
`
So it seems that free space is taken into account . Thank you @PraveenSripati for pointing me to BlockPlacementPolicyDefault